# Regular Collation issue but collate statement on join still giving same error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
Update 
    AEB
Set 
    [hbs_mailreturned] = 1
from
    AccountExtensionBase AEB 
Inner Join #IndividualsIDs I1  on 
    AEB.hbs_organisationid collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = I1.hbs_individualid collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

It is giving the following error message:

**Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the equal to operation.**

I don't understand this because I have specifying the collation to use on the join statement. What am I missing here?

Comment: what is the collation of the columns ?

Comment: Thanks @Squirrel, have finished up creating a real table and dropping it afterwards. That resolved the problem.

Comment: you could specify the collation for the column while creating the temp table

Comment: Thanks @Squirrel, if you want to purpose that as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will not create issue which you have applied on your columns,

```
AEB.hbs_organisationid collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = I1.hbs_individualid collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

please check for null  for column values applied in join, if still not working then you can try

```
where fieldname COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = secondfieldname COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```